# Write a formal deﬁnition of the statement f is not continuous at a and use it to prove that the following function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, continuity

Write a formal deﬁnition of the statement f is not continuous at a, and use it to prove that the function [$f(x)=x$ if $x≠1$] and [$f(x)=0$ if $x=1$ ] is not continuous at $a = 1$.

please help me with that.

Comment: Working out negation of statements comes only with practice. I would like you to attempt (give it your best shot), the negation of the statement "for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$, such that $|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)| < \epsilon$." It is ok if it is wrong, I will correct it, but I want to at least see where you are placed in this question. (Of course, the above is just the definition of continuity at $a$).

Answer (score 2):

We define discontinuity of a function $f$ if:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x) \neq f(a)$

In this case:

$$a=1$$
$$f(a)=0$$
$$lim_{x \rightarrow 1}f(x)=1$$
$$1 \neq 0$$
Therefore, $f$ is discontinuous (or not continuous) at $a$. This is another way to state the definition in the comment of @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрr that I find usually more intuitive.

The explanation for the definition of continuity and discontinuity can is explained very well at this site, and I recommend it for more intuitive definitions like this: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/Continuity.aspx

Comment: Thank you for referring to my comment. The link is also very helpful for beginners.

Comment: Glad to see you think so. I used it up until and through my studies in Calc III, and I found the definitions very intuitive even when dealing with functions in $n$-dimensions. It really is a very good source.

Comment: I would like to know if you can recommend to the questioner, any good sources on "how to negate mathematical statements". That is helpful even for higher mathematicians, although I learnt it from just practice.

Comment: I myself usually used an informal, personal definition of it. While I use logic often in my proofs, I rarely use formal notation and definitions. Therefore, I do not have many sources good for beginners - I usually just google notation when it is required.

Comment: Ok, great, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

First you write the definition of $f \text{ is continuous at } a$ using a mix of english words and logical symbols:

- For every $\epsilon > 0$ there is at least one $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x$ if $|x - a| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$

Then you rewrite the above expression using only logical symbols:

- $(\forall \epsilon)(\epsilon > 0 \implies (\exists \delta)(\delta > 0 \land (\forall x)(|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon)))$

Next you negate the above expression and begin to manipulate the logical symbols:

- $\neg (\forall \epsilon)(\epsilon > 0 \implies (\exists \delta)(\delta > 0 \land (\forall x)(|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon)))$
- $(\exists \epsilon) \neg (\epsilon > 0 \implies (\exists \delta)(\delta > 0 \land (\forall x)(|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon)))$
- $(\exists \epsilon)(\epsilon > 0 \land \neg (\exists \delta)(\delta > 0 \land (\forall x)(|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon)))$
- $(\exists \epsilon)(\epsilon > 0 \land (\forall \delta) \neg (\delta > 0 \land (\forall x)(|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon)))$
- $(\exists \epsilon)(\epsilon > 0 \land (\forall \delta)(\delta \leq 0 \lor \neg (\forall x)(|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon)))$
- $(\exists \epsilon)(\epsilon > 0 \land (\forall \delta)(\delta \leq 0 \lor (\exists x) \neg (|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon)))$
- $(\exists \epsilon)(\epsilon > 0 \land (\forall \delta)(\delta \leq 0 \lor (\exists x)(|x - a| < \delta \land \neg(|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon))))$
- $(\exists \epsilon)(\epsilon > 0 \land (\forall \delta)(\delta \leq 0 \lor (\exists x)(|x - a| < \delta \land |f(x) - f(a)| \geq \epsilon)))$

The final expression is a definition of $f \text{ is not continuous at } a$

To prove that your function $f$ is not continuous at $a$ using the above definition first you discard the case where $\delta \leq 0$ because it is not interesting. Why? You can fix for example $\delta = 0$ with $\epsilon > 0$ and you finish your proof.

The interesting case is when $\delta > 0$ and $|x - a| < \delta \land |f(x) - f(a)| \geq \epsilon$. Therefore we need to find at least one $\epsilon > 0$ and $x$ such that for any $\delta > 0$ we have that $|x - a| < \delta \land |f(x) - f(a)| \geq \epsilon$

- $|x - 1| < \delta \land |f(x) - 0| \geq \epsilon$ because $a = 1$ and $f(a) = 0$
- $|x - 1| < \delta \land |f(x)| \geq \epsilon$

Because $\epsilon > 0$ we need that $x \neq 1$. Otherwise $|f(x)| \geq \epsilon$ would imply $|0| \geq \epsilon$ but we need $\epsilon > 0$

- $|x - 1| < \delta \land |f(x)| \geq \epsilon$ and $x \neq 1$
- $|x - 1| < \delta \land |x| \geq \epsilon$ because $f(x) = x$ when $x \neq 1$

To simplify things and because we need to find at least one $x$ we assume that $x-1 >0$. Therefore $|x - 1| = x - 1$ and $|x| = x$ because $x > 1$

- $x - 1 < \delta \land x \geq \epsilon$ for $x > 1$

To simplify even more we assume that $x = \epsilon$

- $x - 1 < \delta \land x = \epsilon$ and $x > 1$

Using the above expression we can fix, for example $x = 2 > 1$, so

- $1 < \delta \land \epsilon = 2$ and $x > 1$

In that sense, there exist at least one $x$ and $\epsilon$ with $x = \epsilon = 2 > 1$ such that

$$(\forall \delta)(\delta \leq 0 \lor (\exists x)(|x - a| < \delta \land |f(x) - f(a)| \geq \epsilon))$$

Therefore your function $f \text{ is not continuous at } a = 1$

If you want to learn more about how to manipulate logical symbols and understand the concepts of $f \text{ is continuous at } a$ and $f \text{ is not continuous at } a$ check out in your local library the book:

- Mendelson, Elliott. 2008. Number Systems and the Foundations of Analysis. Mineola, N.Y: Dover Publications. ISBN-13: 978-0486457925

In particular check out: **Chapter 1 Basic Facts and notions of logic and set theory > 1.4 Quantifiers > Exercises > 3**